# Interesting/Paradoxical Math Problems for High School Students

Tags: education, paradoxes

I am creating a math course for high school students (not necessarily advanced) about interesting/paradoxical math problems (think Monty Hall and Hilbert's Hotel). What are some other interesting math problems that are accessible to average high school students? So no calculus or higher required (unless the necessary machinery can be taught within 30 minutes). Thanks!

Comment: Russell's paradox, Simpson's paradox, Braess's paradox....

Comment: To which we can add the birthday paradox. About Braess's paradox see [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/9688/7858). This site is maybe the best place to ask such a question..

Comment: also the Allais paradox, Bertrand paradox of probabilities, Ellsberg paradox, ... and an honorable mention going to the Bayes formula :) (Btw this course sounds pretty fun - good luck!)

Answer (score 2):

[Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) could be fun. I had a lively discussion with some high school students about whether $0.999999... = 1$, and we enjoyed looking at pictures such as this one:
[image: Geometric series picture]

While this topic comes up against the idea of a limit and infinite series, it doesn't have to be presented with that language.

Comment: "I had a lively discussion with some high school students about whether 0.999999...=1" - isn't that just part of the definition of the ... part?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by the definition of the "... part."  Since the students I was talking to hadn't seen limits before, part of the discussion was what the definitions should be, different ways to represent real numbers, and what it means to add infinitely many terms.

Comment: I see...what I was getting at was: I didn't think this was something that could be figured out (i.e. proved), but rather something that we simply agree should be included in the definition of a repeating decimal (perhaps for good reasons). Is that incorrect?

Comment: I did plan on showing them $0.999... = 1$ via the algebraic proof $$x = 0.999... \Leftrightarrow 10x = 9.999... \Leftrightarrow 9x = 9 \Leftrightarrow x = 1.$$ But what kinds of questions did you ask to spark discussion? @llim

Comment: As I recall, one of the questions that was asked was whether $0.9999...$ is a number, and if so, is it equal to a more familiar number?  Interestingly, the students were very eager to say that it was "equivalent" to 1, but hesitated to say it was "equal" to 1.  This led us to ask what "equivalent" and "equal" meant.  @John B, I agree it can't be proved.  I guess it was an exercise in making good definitions.

Comment: If we extend the concept of paradox, the fact that "$n^2+n+41$ is a prime number" is true for many $n$, until.... (One of the many Euler problems).

Comment: [The missing square puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle)

Comment: For the use of paradoxes in teaching probability :https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330372116_Paradoxical_Simulations_to_Enhance_Education_in_Mathematics. For geometric probabilities, there is the ["Bertrand paradox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) maybe too difficult because needing some preliminary knowledge...